# SQL Join: Tables of the same kind

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to make a `SELECT` query that gets the titles of paintings and sculptures and the corresponding artistID.

Here is the schema:

`Paintings(paintingID, title, painterID) p`

`Sculptures(scluptureID, title, sculptorID) s`

I think I have to use a `JOIN`, but I don't know what to join on without getting strange results. If I join `ON p.painterID=s.sculptorID` then I only get results for artists who are both painters and sculptors. I want to get all the sculptures and paintings, treating them as 'art' and treating painters and sculptures as 'artists' so that each row would contain all the values, filling in colums that don't exist in the other table with `NULL`s (the schema is a bit larger in real life). How would I go about doing that / what am I missing?

Comment: You should correct `scluptures` for `sculptures`. Also this is a [many to many relationship](http://sqlrelationship.com/many-to-many-relationship/) you should read about it. You need to use [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms180026.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a Join, you need to use an [UNION](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx) query:

```
SELECT title, painterID artistID
FROM Paintings
UNION ALL
SELECT title, sculptorID artistID
FROM Sculptures
```

This will select all paintings from `Paintings` table, and all sculptures from `Sculptures` table. Both `painterID` and `sculptorID` will have an alias of `artistID`.